# TeamCity: how to attach dotcover to Rake build configuration?

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I'm using Rake for my build process. I wanted to take advantage of included dotcover in TeamCity 6. I read tutorial from Hadi Hariri (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/coverage-with-dotcover-teamcity-mstest-nunit-or-mspec/) but it shows how to do this with MSBuild, not Rake.

When you choose RunnerType: MSbuild, you have the ".net coverage tool" option available at the bottom. However, when you choose Rake, you don't have this at all.

Do I need to create a custom msbuild file to run coverage ? Or are there any tricks that would allow me to just keep additional task in my single rake file ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find dotCover executable on `$(teamcity.agent.home.dir)\plugins\dotCover\bin`.